# error when pushing Managed Package into scratch org: ISV

Tags: managed-package, error-messages, salesforcedx, scratch-org, push

Implementing SFDX for some new work. Here is what I have so far, the Dev Hub is a business org, created a project, created a scratch org, retrieved a managed package via the MetadataAPI, unzipped the file, and converted it. Smooth sailing.

When pushing this into the scratch org, I am getting a dozen or so errors. Errors such as:

```
"no CustomField named CustomObjectName__c.Response_text__c found" 

"Invalid definition for PackageName:LightningCmpNameComponentController: null"
```

I have checked that the "missing" items throwing the errors (above, the custom object/custom field, Lightning component) are included in the managed package. I am adding the temporary MetadataAPI retrieval folders at the project root, where the config/ and force-app/ directories are. 
As far as I can tell from the docs, this is the correct place for that to happen. Not sure what I am missing here.

Any ideas out there? They will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the business org, this package I'm trying to install is an installed package (Setup/Installed Packages) vs. appearing in the package manager (Setup/Package Manager/Packages). Not sure  if this makes a difference or not.

Comment: UPDATE I figured out the issue! I was following the winter 18 [SFDX developer guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/210/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/sfdx_dev.pdf) under Project Setup: Retrieve Source from an Existing Managed Package. I was retrieving the package from the MetadataAPI, unzipping, then converting it. But, I needed to follow [these](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_build_man_pack_install.htm) instructions instead.

Comment: Be sure to add this as the answer below so we can vote on that. Inter 24 hours of posting your own answer you can mark your own answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

I figured out the issue! I was following the
[Winter 18 SFDX Developer Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/210/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/sfdx_dev.pdf) under Project Setup: Retrieve Source from an Existing Managed Package. I was retrieving the package from the MetadataAPI, unzipping, then converting it. But, I needed to follow these [install package in a target org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_build_man_pack_install.htm) steps instead.

If anyone would like to chime in on why the first source was not working, please share your thoughts. I am glad a solution was found, but would love a bit more understanding on this issue. Thanks!